# "You must add a reference to assembly PresentationFramework" -- but why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am really newbie to c# and VS2010.  :-\

I have a "pure" Winforms application.  Or at least I think so.

But suddenly (with the last changes to the source code) I have this error when build an auxiliary DLL:

> Error 7
> The type
> 'System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost' is
> defined in an assembly that is not
> referenced. You must add a reference
> to assembly '**PresentationFramework**,
> Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. D:\MyprojectPath\SharedExceptions.cs    AuxLibraryProject

I don't want to add *PresentationFramework.dll* to the project and even when I have tried to add it then a lot of other assemblies are required. :-(

I want to know WHERE is the guilty of this assembly requirement.   I will be happy to blame some line on my source code but I cannot find it.

The `SharedExceptions.cs` is one of the files changed but when I (manually) delete all changes, the error persists.

This same assembly compiles fine on a Windows XP Visual Studio 2010 system.  But not on Windows Vista.

---

**Update:**

I have left alone the parent exception for all others.  All other are on other files.  After rebuild, the error remains on the same file.  Here is the little source code.  I cannot see anything requiring the new assembly:

```
using System;

    namespace PROJECT.AuxLibraryProject
    {
        public class SharedExceptionParent: Exception
        {
             public string ErrorMessage
             {
                 get
                 {
                     return base.Messsage.ToString();
                 }
             }
             public SharedExceptionParent() { }
             public SharedExceptionParent(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) { }
             public SharedExceptionParent(string errorMessage, Exception innerEx) : base(errorMessage, innerEx) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added any other references to the project?

Comment: I must remember this compiles fine on a Windows XP.  With same subversion tree update.  It only fail on Windows Vista.   I am trying to check another update on another Windows XP workstation from a colleague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have found it:**

This line on top of namespace keyword on two assemblies was the culprit:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

I have deleted this line on both assemblies and all builds fine now.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You are either referencing `HwndHost`, or something you added is referencing `HwndHost`.  This is defined in PresentationFramework.dll.

You'll need to track down the culprit.  It's in your `SharedExceptions.cs` file.  There is obviously at least one change that didn't get backed out completely in that file.

(This, btw, is one huge advantage of using one file per class... I'm guessing that you have MANY exception types defined in that file, which is why you're not just seeing this instantly.)

Comment: Yes, all exceptions are in that .cs file.  :-(  
But there is only five exceptions inside so I can separate in several files even only to find the culprit.   I'll do it and return with results so perhaps I can be a bit more concrete to find it.